# .htaccess goes wrong with specific hosting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, syntax, hosting, localhost

I have this code in my .htaccess :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php -->
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works very well on my localhost (MAMP) and online with an hosting like MediaTemple but with WAMP and another host like 1and1 it doesn't work!

Do you have any ideas to tweak this for working everywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: I've found on some occasions where a htaccess works somewhere but not somewhere else that it helps to add `RewriteBase`, could be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteBase /` and removing `./` from your `index.php`. In case mod_rewrite isn't available, the 404 redirect should do the trick although I'm not sure how robust your app will be if you end up using it (never had to use that method myself).

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also, your first `RewriteCond` does not appear to be necessary simply because rules 2 and 3 take care of what it's trying to achieve.